# Creating comments in Lex and Yacc

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

How does one make a comment in Lex and Yacc?

So far I haven't tried Yacc, but in Lex I have tried `/* comment */` and `// comment`, but neither of these compile. I am on a Mac, using the builtin Lex and Yacc compilers, (or maybe the X-Code ones, I don't know). What is the correct syntax for comments in Lex or Yacc, or preferably both?

Answer (score 7):

Any **C** comment is acceptable as a comment anywhere in a program in both Yacc and Lex, ***BUT:***

- When using Lex or Yacc whitespace is important, so `/* comment */` written into your program touching the LHS of your text will **NOT WORK!**

  - to make it work, you must add a tab or space to the beginning of the line, to shove it to C code, and not Lex or Yacc code.
- gcc is a nice compiler and loves you very much, so it accepts `// comment` comments, Lex and Yacc are not nice. these comments, while will work in a C program, will **NOT WORK!**

Answer (score 5):

From *info flex*:

> In the definitions and rules sections, any  indented  text
>          or  text  enclosed  in %{ and %} is copied verbatim to the
>          output (with the %{}'s removed).  The  %{}'s  must  appear
>          unindented on lines by themselves.

In this case the text concerned can be a comment in the target language.

> In the definitions section (but not in the rules section),
>          an unindented comment (i.e., a line beginning  with  `/*`)
>          is also copied verbatim to the output up to the next `*/`.

Any valid C comment is a comment in a code block.

A comment in *yacc* is `/* ... */`.

Comment: The Lex comment syntax of `# comment` does not work. (the declaration section is the middle one right?)

Comment: The declarations section is the first one.  The middle one is the rule section.  In the rules section, any indented line (begins with space or tab) is C code copied to the lex.yy.c file, so any C comments are valid and copied and treated as comments by the C compiler

Comment: @ChrisDodd, ah! so `[TAB] /* comment */` and  `[TAB] // comment` should work then.

Comment: @Stegosaurus: yes, though the latter will only work if your C compiler accepts C++-style comments, or you're using a C++ compiler.

Comment: Oops. I was a *flex* user and contributor in the 1980s, but it's been a long time, and the part I wrote about `#` seems to have been complete fantasy. Corrected.

Comment: @EJP is it possible to merge my answer with yours? I think if we do, it would function as a very informative answer that covered all the points necessary.

Comment: @Stegosaurus Why? I don't see anything in your answer that isn't covered in mine more rigorously and with quotations and citations.